# Replace specific columns in a matrix with a constant column vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

For neural networking, I would like to represent a column vector `y = [1;2;3]` in a matrix like so:

```
y = [1 0 0;
     0 1 0;
     0 0 1]
```

My vector `y` is very large, and so hardcoding is not an option.  Also, I would like to avoid using `for`-loops.

What I did so far:

```
y1 =[y; zeros(1,length(y)) ;zeros(1,length(y))] % add two rows with zeros in orde to give y the right format

idx = find(y1(1,:) == 2); % find all the columns containing a 2
y1(:,idx(1):idx(end)) = y1(:,[0;1;0]); % this does not work because now I am comparing a matrix with a vector
```

I also tried this:

```
y1( y1 == [2;0;0] )=[0;1;0]; % This of course does not work
```

Is there a way to specify I want to compare columns in  `y1 == [2;0;0]`, or is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the context of your question, you wish to find a matrix where each column is an **identity vector**.  For an identity vector, each column in this matrix is a non-zero vector where 1 is set in the position of the vector denoted by each position of `y` and 0 otherwise.  Therefore, let's say we had the following example:

```
y = [1 5 4 3]
```

You would have `y_out` as the final matrix, which is:

```
y_out =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

---

There are several ways to do this.  The easiest one would be to declare the identity matrix with [`eye`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html), then let `y` pick out those columns that you want from this matrix and place them as columns into your final matrix.  If `y` had all unique values, then we would simply be rearranging the columns of this identity matrix based on `y`.  As such:

```
y_out = eye(max(y));
y_out = y_out(:,y)

y_out =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

---

Another way would be to declare a [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) matrix, where each row index is simply those elements from `y` and each column index is increasing from 1 up to as many elements as we have `y`:

```
y_out = sparse(y, 1:numel(y), 1, max(y), numel(y));
y_out = full(y_out)

y_out =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

---

One more way would be to use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to find linear indices into your matrix, then access those elements and set them to 1.  Therefore:

```
ind = sub2ind([max(y) numel(y)], y, 1:numel(y));
y_out = zeros(max(y), numel(y));
y_out(ind) = 1

y_out =

     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: Please consider editing the title of the question; it is not relevant to the topics explained here.

Comment: @erfan I haven't changed it as this is the title I am accustomed to for this question and it was asked almost 2 years ago.  Everyone I know who uses this as a duplicate since that point uses this as the question title when searching for this duplicate.  However, if you have a suggestion on what title to use, I would certainly be welcome to them.

Comment: I actually could not come up with a good replacement. I just found it impossible for a new user to find this post from the title. But I think it is not very necessary, since if a similar concept is discussed in a duplicate with a better chosen title, that would eventually lead people to this post.

Answer (score 2):

This works even if `y` has "missing" values:

```
n = numel(y);
y_matrix = zeros(n, max(y));
y_matrix((1:n) + (y-1)*n) = 1;
```

Example:

```
y = [1 5 3 2];
```

gives

```
y_matrix =
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
```

Comment: Very nice :) Much faster than `sub2ind` as you're computing the indices directly.

Comment: Minor note: You might want to transpose the result because each result in the output is meant to be a column vector... then again, I'm not quite sure what the OP wants!

Comment: A nice solution too! I figured I had to transpose the result (but that was the case in rayryeng's solution as well).

Comment: So @rayryeng was right in his suggestion. In fact, I couldn't tell from your question exactly what you wanted

Comment: @LuisMendo - Neither could I, but given that the question had the word "columns", that was my best guess.

Comment: @PepijnvanDiepen - I found a small bug in my code.  Once I fixed this, you don't have to transpose your result anymore.  Check my edits out whenever you have time.  Thanks for accepting my answer BTW!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`bsxfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
y_out =  bsxfun(@eq, (1:max(y)).', y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as efficient as the @rayryeng's answer but this might also help,

Also if there are repeated values in `y` this code works fine.

```
a = [1 2 3 2 5 7 6 8];
[X,Y] = meshgrid(a,1 : length(a));
A = X == Y;

A =

 1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```