# How to generate label matrix from a label vector?

Tags: matlab

I've a label vector as follows:

```
   y=[3 1 5 3 4 2];
```

Is there any efficient way to generate the following label matrix?

```
    [0 0 1 0 0;
     1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1;
     0 0 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;]
```

**UPDATED:**
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216257/replace-specific-columns-in-a-matrix-with-a-constant-column-vector) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix) are both good answers. Using the scripts provided by @Nras, the following is to handle the missing labels:

```
    Y=[3 1 5 3 4 2];
    labels=unique(Y);
    [~,indexes]=ismember(Y,labels);
    rows = 1:length(Y); %// row indx
    T = zeros(length(Y),length(unique(indexes))); %// A matrix full of zeros
    T(sub2ind(size(T),rows ,indexes)) = 1; %// Ones at the desired row/column combinations
```

Comment: also duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150174/creating-indicator-matrix

Comment: Minor note:  The duplicate applies for generating matrices where the **columns** denote the non-zero values.  Simply transpose the result to get a row matrix as seen in your question.  BTW, thanks for linking to my answer @Shai :)

Comment: @rayryeng there are quite a few threads that are practically the same here (I even think I have answered one of them...), but IMHO this question is most "canonical".

Comment: @Shai, thank you! The post you provided indeed is very good solution. Because when I made this post, I didn't checked your post, thus I made this duplicate post. And I've closed this post. Maybe the stackoverflow could improve the natural language processing techniques to offer the most preferable suggestions when we write down the title of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub2ind` for this problem. Your `y` determines the columns to use, 
the rows are simply always incremented by 1. By using `sub2ind` the desired row-column-combinations get transformed to a linear index and can then all be adressed in a vectorized way.

```
y = [3 1 5 3 4 2]; %// column indx
rows = 1:length(y); %// row indx

M = zeros(length(y), max(y)); %// A matrix full of zeros
M(sub2ind(size(M),rows ,y)) = 1; %// Ones at the desired row/column combinations
```

Comment: But I suggest you could add the `unique` function into your answer because the `y` vector may not have the label `2` or other values.

Comment: @hubberwinston - The duplicate answer can handle cases where labels are missing.

Comment: @rayryeng, thank you for indicating that. The post you provided is very good solution.