# Why this Octave code won't work?

Tags: matrix, octave

Let `Y` be a vector of length `N`, containing numbers from `1` to `10`. As example code you can use:

```matlab
Y = vec(1:10);
```

I am writing the code which must create an `N x 10` matrix, each row consisting of all zeros except for a `1` only in the position which corresponds to the number in vector `Y`. Thus, `1` in `Y` becomes `10000000000`, `3` becomes `0010000000`, and so on.

This approach works:

```matlab
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)eye(10)(x,:), Y, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

My next idea was to "optimize", so `eye(10)` is not generated `N` times, and I wrote this:

```matlab
theEye = eye(10);
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x)theEye(x,:), Y, 'UniformOutput', false))
```

However, now Octave is giving me error:

```
error: can't perform indexing operations for diagonal matrix type
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
```

**Why do I get this error? What is wrong?**

Bonus questions — do you see a better way to do what I am doing? Is my attempt to optimize making things easier for Octave?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6150174/97160

Comment: reported as [Octave bug](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47510)

Comment: Heh look at that. It's an actual bug. Thanks for reporting it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran this code in Octave and `eye` creates a matrix of a class (or whatever this is) known as a  `Diagonal Matrix`:

```
octave:3> theEye = eye(10);
octave:4> theEye
theEye =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

In fact, the documentation for Octave says that if the matrix is diagonal, a special object is created to handle the diagonal matrices instead of a standard matrix: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Creating-Diagonal-Matrices.html

What's interesting is that we can slice into this matrix outside of the `arrayfun` call, regardless of it being in a separate class.

```
octave:1> theEye = eye(10);
octave:2> theEye(1,:)
ans =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

However, as soon as we put this into an `arrayfun` call, it decides to crap out:

```
octave:5> arrayfun(@(x)theEye(x,:), 1:3, 'uni', 0)
error: can't perform indexing operations for diagonal matrix type
```

This to me doesn't make any sense, especially since we can slice into it outside of `arrayfun`.  One may suspect that it has something to do with `arrayfun` and since you are specifying `UniformOutput` to be false, a cell array of elements is returned per element in `Y` and perhaps something is going wrong when storing these slices into each cell array element.

However, this doesn't seem to be the culprit either.  I took the first three rows of `theEye`, placed them into a cell array and merged them together using `cell2mat`:

```
octave:6> cell2mat({theEye(1,:); theEye(2,:); theEye(3,:)})
ans =

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

<s>As such, I suspect that it may be some sort of internal bug (if you could call it that...).</s>  Thanks to user carandraug (see comment above), this is indeed a bug and it has been reported: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?47510. What may also provide insight is that this code runs as expected in MATLAB.

In any case, one thing you can take away from this is that I would seriously refrain from using `cell2mat`. Just use straight up indexing:

```
Y = vec(1:10);
theEye = eye(10);
out = theEye(Y,:);
```

This would index into `theEye` and extract out the relevant rows stored in `Y` and create a matrix where each row is zero except for the corresponding value seen in each element `Y`.

Also, have a look at this post for a similar example: [Replace specific columns in a matrix with a constant column vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216257/replace-specific-columns-in-a-matrix-with-a-constant-column-vector/27216411#27216411)

However, it is defined over the columns instead of the rows, but it's very similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: @SerhiiYakovenko You're welcome :) To be honest I don't know why the error is happening... but I would suggest just indexing into the rows of the matrix instead.  It's much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know we can do this with indexes :)

Comment: @SerhiiYakovenko You're very welcome.  I'm not sure if I have answered your question... but I did do some experiments to figure out the problem. I'm chalking it up to some internal bug (if you can call it that...).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach; We start with the data:

```
>> len = 10;                % max number
>> vec = randi(len, [1 7])  % vector of numbers
vec =
     1    10     9     5     7     3     6
```

Now we build the indicator matrix:

```
>> I = full(sparse(1:numel(vec), vec, 1, numel(vec), len))
I =
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: `sparse` is my other go-to if it weren't for indexing into the identity matrix. +1.